# Multiple JButtons, one Eventlistener in Java

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, event-listener

I have a 2D-Array of JButtons

```
JButton[][] ledBtns = new JButton[8][8];
```

And in a loop, I do all the init stuff. Now I want to add an EventListener to each JButton, that fires when the Button os clicked. Then I want to change the image on the Button.

```
for(int i = 0; i < ledBtns.length; i++){
  for(int j = 0; j < ledBtns[i].length; j++){
     //init stuff
     ledBtns[i][j].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
       changeImage();
  }
});
  }
}
```

Now 'changeImage()' will be called, but I need to know what button called it.
I can't use parameters, if I do it tells me to declare them as 'final'.
Is there any other way than writing 64 methods, that do exactly the same, and adding them manually to each of the JButtons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to just declare two temporary final ints, and reference those.

```
for(int i = 0; i < ledBtns.length; i++){
  for(int j = 0; j < ledBtns[i].length; j++){
    //init stuff
    final int finalI = i;
    final int finalJ = j;
    ledBtns[i][j].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
      changeImage(finalI,finalJ);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The [`ActionEvent`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionEvent.html) class has a [`getSource()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html#getSource%28%29) method used to get the component that generated the event.

Comment: +1 plus put JButtons to the ButtonModel, HashMap, Action, setName, or putClientProperty()

Answer (score 2):

You can set the JButton object's "name" property and, according to mre's answer, you can call the getSource() method. So you can identity whick button is clicked

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to have your class implement ActionListner (ie, `implements ActionListner`).

Then when  you cycle through your buttons in your loop, you can just say 
`ledBtns[i][j].addActionListener(this)`.

Of course, then you have to figure out which object was the source of the event (usually by using `if...else` blocks). Now that could get unwieldy for 64 objects, but for lesser items, it isn't usually a problem.

Or, you could have the `actionPerformed` method call change image and pass in the button object, etc to do your work on.

What I've suggested is just another option. I'd do what makes the most sense for your code and is the cleanest and most readable.